# What does SNIR stand for?

Tags: terminology, snir

I know that SNOT means "Studs Not On Top", but I've also seen "SNIR" used, [often in the same context as SNOT](http://news.lugnet.com/announce/?n=2692), but clearly different - what does it mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

SNIR is the abbreviation for "**S**tuds **N**ot **I**n a **R**ow" - almost self-explaining, but for more information, take a look at [this small article](http://awesomelegostuff.blogspot.com/2011/08/snir-studs-not-in-row.html).

> [image: SNIR]
>
> [...] very useful on walls and other things. In Lego, studs (nubs, dots, etc.) are in a row, and a straight one. Using SNIR  makes studs be in zigzags or diagonal lines. [...]

Comment: I've seen pictures of a house on a beach which uses this technique with walls built entirely of 1x1 plates in various shades of grey, and in various orientations (thus not all aligned). I wish i could find it back, because the result was indeed superb

Comment: Found it: [Old fishermans house near the shore, by Reinhard "Ben" Beneke](http://www.brickshelf.com/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi?f=69760), who probably pioneered the technique.

Comment: Told you. Funnily enough, I just noticed now that there's a link to it in the article of Didier Enjary mentionned in the question. It's footnote [2], referred to right after the word "SNIR".

Comment: @Joubarc - I completely missed those footnotes :S